# Controlling a 4 lane DSI display from RasPi 3

Tags: control, display

I have a DSI display which runs on 3 data lanes. Can this be controlled from a Raspberry Pi 3 which has a DSI interface that only supports 2 lanes? Looking for a yes or no with a reason. If you have any way to help it's much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Pinout for Connector On Display:
[image]

Comment: Three data lanes? I guess you meant to say four, like in the question title and the image?